# "some of whom" or "some of them"?

Tags: pronouns

[**Source**](https://issuu.com/thirupathiraog/docs/reading_fill_in_the_blanks_multiple) (page 5)

> 1. Soon, Haring opened a store which he called the Pop Shop, which he hoped would attract a broad range of people. While somewhat controversial among street artists, some of **whom** accused Haring of selling out, the Pop Shop changed the way people thought about the relationship between art and business.
> 2. Soon, Haring opened a store which he called the Pop Shop, which he hoped would attract a broad range of people. While somewhat controversial among street artists, some of **them** accused Haring of selling out, the Pop Shop changed the way people thought about the relationship between art and business.

Generally, WHOM is similar in use to HIM/HER/THEM and WHO is similar in use to HE/SHE/THEY. Hence, the text book discusses the use of WHO vs. WHOM instead of WHOM vs. THEM.

I'm a confused with the use of WHOM and THEM. Please explain.

Comment: @Vinokanth FWIW, *whom* is more appropriate in your sentence (after the edit). You could review "relative pronouns" and "relative clauses" in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

> While somewhat controversial among street artists, some of whom accused Haring of selling out.
>
> While somewhat controversial among street artists, some of them accused Haring of selling out.

I don't see this as a choice between *whom* or *them* but rather simple grammar to make the sentence correct.  In the first example, "some of whom ..." is an adjective phrase that modifies "artists".  In the second, everything after the comma could be considered a separate sentence.

What makes this sentence quirky is the "while".  This makes the entire first part of each sentence an adjectival phrase that modifies "Pop Shop".

With the first sentence there are phrases both before and after the comma.  Two phrases do not make a complete sentence, so the first sentence is incomplete and grammatically incorrect.  *However*, the second sentence is also wrong.  Everything before the comma modifies a noun that's not even part of the sentence, so it makes little sense and is generally just poor English.

Here's how the sentences ought to be written:

> **This shop was** somewhat controversial among street artists, some of whom accused Haring of selling out.
>
> **This shop was** somewhat controversial among street artists, **and** some of them accused Haring of selling out.

Given the intended meaning of both sentences, there's no reason to use "while", period.  Otherwise, you can use either "whom" or "them", as both convey the same meaning.

Comment: "[T]he second sentence is also wrong"? I'm not sure if *"While somewhat controversial among street artists, some of them accused Haring of selling out."* is that different from *[While controversial, there are those who, like Riley, clearly believe that the UK is the best place to 'consider taking the next brave steps' (Flinter, 2014), given the supportive framework of the legislation and the experience of the regulatory authority (the HFEA).](https://books.google.com/books?id=qqXwCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT26)*

Comment: @DamkerngT. what or who is controversial?  "Those"?  "Riley"? The "belief"? "The UK"? The "next brave steps"?  The "supportive framework"?  The "legislation"?  The "experience"?  The "regulatory authority"?  Or the overall inscrutable *gestalt* of all of these?

Comment: Point is, it's an ugly sentence that gets no sympathy from me.  If you forced me to pick which of these two sentences was grammatically "correct", I'd go with the second, but I would resent it.